# Xcode 10.3 - Unable to copy symbols from this device

Tags: xcode, symbols

My MAC is running Catalina 10.15 Beta and my iphone is running iOS 12.4.1. My Xcode is: 10.3 (10G8)

When I run, I get this problem:

[image: Unable to copy symbols]

Rebooting my MAC, my phone, unplugging/plugging my phone don't help.

I even tried to delete symbol files under `/Users/Quan/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` and relaunch Xcode, but things are not better.

How can I solve this?

=======EDIT1========

I just noticed the globe icon next to my phone name, which means that Xcode is trying to connect to my phone via network.

Then I go to Windows - Devices and Simulators - Select my device on the left pane and uncheck "Connect via network". I want to make sure Xcode is really connecting to my phone via USB cable.

Xcode now does not event recognize my phone any more (my phone does not appear in the list to download/test).

I go checking the iOS version that my Xcode can currently work on:

Xcode official version (10.3)

[image]

Xcode beta (11.0 beta 3)

[image]

Xcode does not work with my phone, it it because my phone is 12.4.1?